# Dynamic Official Receipt increment algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, django

I made a function that would automatically generate official receipt for POS. it is able to accept format such as **xxx**, **xxx-xxx**, **xx-xx**.

But my code is really messy and horrible and it needs review. I would really appreciate for corrections, recommendations and critiques to improve this.

The flow would be:

1. Get the last official receipt number OR, if none use specified system default.
2. If there is a provided format, use it. and read the last number according to its format
3. Split it, convert it to int and increment it.
4. Check it doesn't exist yet.
5. Return the next official receipt number

I'm using Django/Python. If it needs explanation please comment and I will explain the best way I can.

```
try:
    user = request.user.id
    official_receipt = {}
    default = {}
    company = get_current_company(request)

    or_from_last_transaction = ""
    or_from_default_company = ""

    try:
        try:
            official_receipt = Pointofsale.objects.filter(company=company,is_or_manual=False).values('official_receipt').order_by('-official_receipt').first()
        except Exception as e:
            or_from_last_transaction = '10000'
        else:
            pass
        finally:
            or_from_last_transaction = official_receipt['official_receipt']
        try:
            POS_settings.objects.filter(company=company).exists()
        except POS_settings.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            or_from_default_company = '00000'
        finally:
            default_company = POS_settings.objects.filter(company=company).values().first()
            if default_company['is_or_per_company']:
                or_from_default_company = default_company['pos_official_receipt']
            else:
                or_from_default_company = None

    except Exception as e:
        official_receipt = '30000'
    else:
        pass
    finally:
        official_receipt = or_from_default_company if or_from_default_company else or_from_last_transaction

    stop = True
    duplicate_add = 0

    if any(c.isalpha() for c in official_receipt):
        return 'Incorrect OR Format'

    while stop:
        str_group = official_receipt.split("-")
        str_length = len(official_receipt)
        group_length = int(len(str_group))

        for index, group in reversed(list(enumerate(str_group))):
            limit = len(group)
            group = int(group)
            group += 1
            if len(str(group)) > limit:
                if index == 0:
                    str_group[index] = group
                else:
                    str_group[index] = 0
            else:
                str_group[index] = int(str_group[index]) + (1 + duplicate_add)
                str_group[index] = str(str_group[index]).zfill(limit)
                break

        next_official_receipt = ''
        for group in str_group:
            next_official_receipt += str(group)
            next_official_receipt += '-'

        next_official_receipt = next_official_receipt[0:len(next_official_receipt)-1]
        if Pointofsale.objects.filter(official_receipt=next_official_receipt,company=company).exists():
            stop = True
            duplicate_add += 1
        else:
            stop = False
    return next_official_receipt
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes on the use of exceptions:

- You're catching the non-specific `Exception`. That's bad, because it hides real programming errors. You should be specific what exception to catch (like `except POS_settings.DoesNotExist:`).
- There are too many try-except blocks overall. You may need to rethink what you're trying to do, and with the previous point in mind, what exceptions you're trying to catch. Django queries may often return an empty queryset instead of raising an exception, which may be better suited.
- The overarching try-except is really bad. Firstly, that catches anything that isn't caught in the inner block, and secondly, it makes it hard to read where it starts and ends. Try-except blocks should be short, concentrated around the code code (one or a few lines at most) that might raise the exception
- If you use `else: pass` in an try-except clause (or in an if-clause), it's cleaner to just leave off the `else` branch. There's no use for it. The same goes for `finally: pass`.
- You're catching the overarching exception, then *print*ing it, then returning it. That has two problems:

  - when run inside a proper server, `print` very likely causes problems (from my experience using Apache). Use the Django logging provided.
  - there is absolutely nothing to gain by *returning* an exception. Re-raise it, or perform a cleanup action (and possibly still re-raise it after that). Return is for actual values, not exceptions.

Comment: Thank you Evert, i'll update the code and post it again.